# C# Creating and opening file in isolation throws IOException

Tags: c#, filestream

I made this small program that demonstrates my problem.  It creates the file, and then tries to open it at the same address. An IOException Sharing violation on path is thrown when it tries to open the file. Why does this happen? I can see that the file is being created.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileTestProject
{
class MainClass
{
    private static string address = "/Users/jamessullivan/Desktop/testFile.dat";

    public static void Main ()
    {
        File.Create(address);
        FileStream file = File.Open(address, FileMode.Open);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see problem looking into documentation.

Although your example is meaningless, here is an explanation of problem.

`Create.File(string)` returns `FileStream` which holds unmanaged resource called file handle so you can't create another `FileStream` which which should hold the same handle.

Thous, you should free up the resource after reusing it.

This is a simple consept:

```
using(File.Create(address))
{}

using(FileStream file = File.Open(address, FileMode.Open)
{
}
```

Comment: Why two steps? Just use File.Create once.

Comment: My mistake was not seeing that File.Create returns the file,and it needed to be closed, but was left open. Using the keyword using or storing the reference into a variable and calling file.Close() fixes the problem. Thanks

Comment: @usr, I've mentioned `Although your example is meaningless`. But as OP mentioned `this small program that demonstrates my problem` in real problem it can be a flow where it has meaning.